# add new file in place of existing file in yocto environment

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to add new c file in place of file that already comes after downloading the package from git.Tried bbappend but the original file is still there.also modified src_uri += file://fileone.c but that is also not overwriting file.
Any suggestions would be of great help

Regards
Mayank

Answer (score 3):

This is where `devtool modify` can be very helpful if you're using the jethro (2.0) release or later. Assuming you have already sourced the environment setup script:

1. `devtool modify <recipename>`
2. It will tell you where it has extracted the source - `cd` into that directory.
3. Make the changes to the file that you want - which could be overwriting it completely.
4. `git commit -a` to commit your changes
5. `devtool update-recipe <recipename> -a /path/to/your/custom/layer` (assuming you want to create a bbappend in a custom layer, otherwise just omit the `-a` and path to apply the changes to the original recipe instead).
6. If you are completely finished, you can `devtool reset <recipename>` to put everything back to building completely from the metadata.

Comment: This works beautifully. But can this method be used for adding install_appends? or we must write it by hand on the generated bbappend?

Answer (score 2):

So the original C file is part of the release tarball (or git, or wherever the release comes from) and you want to replace that file with your own before configure and compile happen?

Replacing the whole file is just a special case of any smaller changes you might want to do the source files, so just do what you would do in those cases: create a patch the replaces the file and add the patch with `SRC_URI += file://replace-file-with-my-file.patch`.

I use this work flow (in the project source directory, e.g. poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/my-project):

```
# initialize git (only if this is not a git repo already) 
git init
git add *
git commit -m "original code" 
# <--- here you should replace the file
git commit -a -m "Replace file with a better file"
git format-patch -1
```

Now you should have a patch file that you can copy into the proper recipe directory.